# REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY different designs

Tags: abap

I want to build a normal ALV-list with ABAP. 
I´m using the  function module REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY.
At the moment my code Looks like this

```
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
    EXPORTING
      i_callback_program = z_repid
      i_grid_title       = ls_title
      is_layout          = ps_layout
      it_fieldcat        = lt_fieldcat
      i_save             = gs_save
      is_variant         = gs_variant
    TABLES
      t_outtab           = mytable.
```

My program works fine and the output I get is ok.
But I want to use more attitudes for different style / layout definitions in the ALV.
The reason is, the ALV-list includes a lot of values,
and is made up of two different internal tables ("mytable_a" and "mytable_b" i´ve added to "mytable", which is for output). 
I want the tables to look different, but don´t know which possibilitys I get to implement this.

At the beginning of my project I wanted to build a ALV Tree Control,
but I have no Idea how to interpret the different function modules for this.

Can Anybody can give me a simple example how to build ALV_Tree_Control (I know the demo-programs in SAP, but they won´t help me) or can tell me what possibilities I have with the normal ALV Grid?

I hope you understand my problem, 
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure it can be much clearer than the demo programs. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Are you set on using a single ALV? I think it might be pretty simple to add a splitter and have a separate ALV for `mytable_a` and `mytable_b`.

Comment: I can´t imagine what you mean, do you have an example?